# Why does jquery, or jqmobile, fetch a list of TLD's form mozilla in chrome?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed this in the js console:

```
XHR finished loading: "https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1". jquery.js:3
```

Why does it need a list of TLD's?
Why does it fetch it from mozilla?
If it's needed, can I get it to fetch it from my server?
Does Chrome do this, or jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is being caused by the Chrome Browser Extension Disconnect.

See: https://github.com/disconnectme/disconnect/issues/130

Comment: Thanks for this! This issue was driving me nuts on Safari. I ended up spending over an hour researching what was causing XHR errors in my code. Turns out it was the delete.me extension.